# using an index variable for multiple while loops

Tags: loops, rust, shadowing

I have multiple while loops inside a for loop, and I want to use the index of the current loop as the starting value of both while loops like this:

```rust
for n in 0..10 {
    let mut j = n;
    while j > 0 {
        j/=2;
    }
    j = n;
    while j > 0 {
        j/=2;
    }
}
```

I've heard of shadowing but I can't think of a way to have it limited to the inside of the while loop and also be the condition for the while loop. I feel like there should be a better way to do this but I can't find it anywhere. is this really the correct way to do this or is there a nicer way I'm not seeing?

Comment: (1) There is no way to define the variable inside the loop and use it in the loop condition. (2) There is no shadowing in your code, and I can't see how shadowing is even relevant. The code you have is the simplest I can think of.

Comment: @PitaJ the reason I mention shadowing is because this seems like a thing that shadowing would be useful for. to have the same variable name as the outer loop but return to the outer context value when the loop finishes

Comment: You mean by doing something like `let mut n = n;`? I guess you could, but I don't really see how that's useful. Also you would have to put it in a block in order to do it twice, because of the shadowing.

Comment: You could potentially avoid the issue entirely by using some iterator type that does what you want. Like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50ba4329b5592cf02a713413d5c26cd7). Though it seems pretty subjective which is "clearer".

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is to be achieved is not quite clear. If you want to run through the `for` loop with a new starting value, use a `'label` for the `for` loop.

```
'outer: for n in 0..10 {
    let mut j = n;
    if j > 0 {
        while j > 0 {
            j /= 2;
            println!("{j}");
        }
        continue 'outer; 
    }
    j = n;
    if j > 0 {
        while j > 0 {
            j /= 2;
            println!("{j}");
        }
        continue 'outer; 
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=606d5e0a3957b4b130380c40fd11e1dc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you intend to do, so if you could edit your question to clarify it, that would help us help you!

Are you looking for a way to not reuse the same `j` between the two while loops? You could write:

```rust
for n in 0..10 {
    let mut j = n;
    while j > 0 {
        j/=2;
    }
    let mut j = n; // That's shadowing.
    while j > 0 {
        j/=2;
    }
}
```